# list_editable and widgets

Tags: django, django-admin

When using [list_editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) in `ModelAdmin`, is there any way to change the widget used for the editable fields? I can't find anything in the documentation. Seems like this would be something you'd be able to customize.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, the field in question is a DateTime field, and the default date time widget that django uses takes up a lot of space and doesn't really work in a grid format. I'd like to replace it with a simple `TextInput` widget.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Override `get_changelist_form` method of your `ModelAdmin` class, like so:

```
def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
  kwargs.setdefault('form', MyAdminForm)
  return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_changelist_form(request, **kwargs)
```

And separately define the modified `MyAdminForm`:

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
     model = MyModel
  my_field = forms.DateField(widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget())
```

This is just an example which will make `my_field` represented by a widget for only the date (without time). That looks much better in the list view.

Comment: Why do You use super() in ``get_changelist_form``? In documentation they just use ``return ModelForm`` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist_form ...

Comment: I've just noticed, it is 2 years old question :)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to change **widget only** (tested on `django 1.5`) you won't need to set labels ect. just use this syntax:

```
from django import forms

class OfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        widgets = {
            'description' : forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'cols': '20',
                }
            )
        }
```

Where `widgets` dict is dict whose keys are names of fields and values represents widgets you want to override.

As [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist_form) states for django 1.5+ its also possible to just:

```
class OfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        return OfferForm
```

Without any `super()` and `kwargs` juggling.