# ManyToManyField widget in a django admin change list?

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-admin, manytomanyfield

In the change list of the django admin, I want to use list_editable to display a django-autocomplete widget for a ManyToManyField.

I found something similar here: [list_editable and widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065982/list-editable-and-widgets)

Normally including a ManyToManyField in list_display raises an ImproperlyConfigured exception, eg:

> ""'BookAdmin.list_display[2]', 'author' is a ManyToManyField which is not supported."

I (perhaps unwisely) removed 3 lines from contrib/admin/validate.py to bypass the exception. :)

I now have it spitting out the following, which is close(?) but no cigar.

> <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x1032a85d0>

Any thoughts on how to proceed? Is there a better way of doing this?

Here's what I have at the moment: (AuthorAutocomplete is working fine in the regular admin form)

```
class AuthorAutocomplete(AutocompleteSettings):
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')

class BookAdmin(AutocompleteAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
      kwargs.setdefault('form', AuthorAutocompleteForm)
      return super(BookAdmin, self).get_changelist_form(request, **kwargs)    
      list_display = ['isbn', 'title', 'author', 'publisher']
      #...

class AuthorAutocompleteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = Book
    author = AuthorAutocomplete
```

Thanks!

Comment: Bad developer, BAD. Never, never, ever change the Django source. I haven't tried to do this myself, but if the admin app explicitly forbids `ManyToManyFields` there's a reason for it. Something somewhere is incapable of functioning properly in the process of saving the model. If it's a feature that's important to you, consider filing a bug for it. Otherwise, you may just be out of luck. Patching the Django source is going to create a maintenance nightmare for you and any poor developer that happens to inherit your code in the future.

Answer (score 8):

To get the values for a ManyToMany field in your own code so you can display their values you can do the following. I'm using `list_display` as an example.

```py
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_some_value(self):
        return ", " . join([x.__str__() for x in self.manytomany_field.all()])
    get_some_value.short_description = 'Title'  # sets column header title

    list_display = ('get_some_value',)  # define Model's fields to be presented on admin changelist
```

where `manytomany_field` is [the name you gave your `manytomany_field`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15192954/1048186) and `get_some_value` is a method within the class which is assigned a `short_description`.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. what is `list_display`? It would be much more helpful to provide a full example to display a list of a many to many field with a specific name

Comment: Links to the docs on this subject would help provide context to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. I thought that William's manytomany_field was a built-in ModelAdmin object. So I ran his code as is (after putting in the missing parenthesis after join).

Strange to say, it ran without producing an error message. But (None) appeared when I was supposed to get values. And I thought it was strange that I couldn't find anything when I Googled "django model.Admin.manytomany_field". Hah!

So eventually I realized that I was to put the NAME of the many-to-many field in place of manytomany_field. It works!