# Edit multiselect field?

Tags: django, django-admin

So I have a ManyToMany field in my model and Django admin renders it as a multiselect field. It works fine and I have no issues — except that I can't **Edit** it after creating a record.
I tried **Del** key, **mouse right-click**, nothing worked. Looks like I have to delete the record and create it again?

[image]

This is the field I want to edit. I want to remove one or two of the above items. I'm on Windows.

Comment: I think you should try this: [How To Edit ManyToManyField In Django Admin list Display Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325438/how-to-edit-manytomanyfield-in-django-admin-list-display-page)

Comment: Hold down "Control", or "Command" as the help text says there. This works the same way for unselecting.

Comment: Tried that several times. Didn't work.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat If I hold ```CTRL``` and deselect **all** items, it works. But if I hold ```CTRL``` and deselect just 2 or 3, it doesn't.

Comment: Are you logged in as a superuser? If not (staff can also login to admin) the issue may be that you don't have _change_ permission for the related model.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like there's a simpler solution:

(Courtesy of [Webdev Hints](https://binary-data.github.io/2015/07/21/django-admin-manytomany-inline-enable-add-edit-buttons/))

Here's my models:

```
class Technology(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Technologies'


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = HTMLField()
    technology = models.ManyToManyField(Technology, related_name='projects')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And the solution is to add the following to the `admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(Technology)
class TechnologyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class TechnologyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Project.technology.through


@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (TechnologyInline,)
    exclude = ('technology',)
```

Now the `ManyToMany` filed is editable.